# Release memory in csv.writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, memory

I have a python script with a loop that:

- open a url
- get information
- store that information in a CSV file

The problem is that the loop has like 1million iterations and I run out of memory after a while. I have been profiling the script and the problem is that the csv writer never release memory. I have been reading about and my implementation seems to be correct and I have even try to release memory manually with 'del csv' and 'gc.collect()' or even close manually the file with no improvements.

Here's a little piece of code:

```
for step in range(0, 1000000):

    retrievedDict = getDictData(x)
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as output_csv_file:
            w = csv.writer(output_csv_file)
            if (step == 0): 
                w.writerow(retrievedDict.keys())
            w.writerow(retrievedDict.values())
            output_csv_file.close() #I know this supposed to be useless.
```

The profile:

```
73   32.922 MiB    0.000 MiB                w = csv.writer(output_csv_file)
74   32.922 MiB    0.000 MiB                if (step == 0):
75   26.883 MiB   -6.039 MiB                    w.writerow(retrievedDict.keys())
76   32.922 MiB    6.039 MiB                w.writerow(retrievedDict.values())
77   32.922 MiB    0.000 MiB                output_csv_file.close()
```

The program starts with 0.5% of memory usage, after 30minutes it has like 3.5%. The only point varying is that line of code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  It's very important in Python.  Hard to say what your program does without proper indentation.  Also, what fraction of the total run is complete by the time 30 minutes have passed?  Or how long do you expect the whole thing to run for?

Comment: If it really is a memory leak, there is nothing you can do from python. Try forcing garbage collection using `import gc; gc.collect()`

Comment: Sorry for the indentation, fixed. just 3000 iterations of 1.000.000, so ~19 days?

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 Why do you keep overwriting the same file?

Comment: I have also tried to use gc.collect(). Please, read the question. And I'm not overwritting anything...

Comment: You are, you open the file as 'w' which overwrites on every loop, change to 'a' for append

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I have a 50K lines files but that was before using the 'with open' statement because the memory problem... fixed.

Comment: And what is x? Shouldnt it  be for x in range? In current code, x is the same every loop, you are writing the same thing to to the same file 1000000 times. Or is there more code underneath?

Comment: There is code above, but its not relevant. The memory problem is in the csv writer